# Match field for each record to specific query record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have 1 table of the form:

```
Study Name ¦ xx ¦ yy ¦ zz ¦ Target No ¦ Current No.
```

This is called study_information

and another of the form:

```
Study Name ¦ Patient Name ¦ Date ¦ Time
```

This is called patient_visits

I have created a query that counts the number of patients for each study name:

```
SELECT patient_visits.study_name, Count(patient_visits.study_name) AS [Count]
FROM patient_visits
GROUP BY patient_visits.study_name;
```

Which gives output for example of:

```
Study Name ¦ Count
Study 1    ¦   4
Study 2    ¦   7
Study 3    ¦   11
```

i.e. there were 4 records (4 patients) in the patient_visits table for Study 1.

What I want to do is display the count in the Current No. field of the study_information table. I have tried setting the datatype of the current no field to lookup the query but it produces a drop down list isntead of matching the study names. I also created a direct relationship betweent the count field of the query and current_no but got the same result.

Hope this is clear; in pseudo:

```
study_information.current_no = COUNT patient_visits.study_name where     study_information.study_name = patient_visits.study_name
```

How do I link these two values up?

Comment: In this kind of scenario should I be displaying a more expanded query instead of storing the data in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `GROUP BY` query is named `qryVisitsPerStudy`, this should give you what you need.  It doesn't store the counts in a `[Current No.]` field in `study_information` like you seemed to want.  But that is a good thing because you won't need to update stored count values whenever the data contained in `patient_visits` changes.

```
SELECT 
    s.[Study Name],
    s.xx,
    s.yy,
    s.zz,
    s.[Target No],
    q.[Count] AS [Current No.]
FROM
    study_information AS s
    INNER JOIN qryVisitsPerStudy AS q
    ON s.[Study Name] = q.study_name
```

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to Access + SQL, so storing the values in a field in `study_information` is poor practice because the values will change. In general I guess we should not be performing calculations in a table field? Using the `s.xx, s.yy` formatting I presume is just so you don't have to write the name of the table everytime since `s` is declared in the `FROM` statement?